# Error when uploading large files from Angular only when it is deployed in Openshift, locally it works fine

Tags: java, angular, kubernetes, openshift, load-balancing

I have an Angular application that allows uploading files with FormData and the API receives it as MultipartFile in Java with Spring.

when I try to upload files larger than 230Mb, after 3-4 min in Java throws this error:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. java.io.EOFException] with root cause java.io.EOFException: null
```

and after 1-2 min the front throws the Gateway Error 504.

- Running the angular application and the API locally, it works correctly
- If I deploy the API in develop environment and upload the file with Postman or Angular App in local, it works fine.
- The error appears only when I deploy the Angular app and try to upload the file from the deployed app.

I tried increasing the timeout in route of openshift with the property haproxy.router.openshift.io/timeout, but still the same problem. I understand that Routers only control external connections and in my case there are 2 PODs within the same cluster.

```
kind: Route
metadata:
  annotations:
    haproxy.router.openshift.io/timeout: 15m
```

I've spent a few days researching and trying to understand the cause of that error, but nothing comes to my mind. I understand that the problem comes from the Openshift configuration, it will have some transfer limitation.

Could the problem come from the load balancer?

I appreciate any help and advice. Thanks.

Comment: You probably have an intermediate proxy somewhere that blocks large requests. Could be a size thing or a timeout thing.